# How to run programs in a github repository

Tags: c++, github, repository

For example, I want to use [WolfDec](https://github.com/Sinflower/WolfDec) but I'm really noob with what GitHub really is and I'm lost, specially with what the developer added in the README.md

`Usage: Just drag and drop one or more .wolf file[s] onto the executable to extract them.`

What does it mean?

Comment: You need to download and compile the program before you can run it.

Comment: Looks like those are execution instructions. It appears first you need to build the executable with Visual Studio or construct 
 and execute suitable build configuration for other toolchains.